# Retornar json en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Amigos necesito ayuda, la pregunta puede que esté un poco confusa me explico:
Estoy usando `laravel 5.6`, y estoy guardado datos desde un formulario y los envío al `controlador`, lo de siempre, pero en el controlador estoy usando  `return response()->json($contacto);` esto me retorna un `json`, hasta ahí bien

Pregunta:

Como hago para que no sea un `Json` si una palabra, que en mi caso es una valor interpretado por un `javascript`

Actualmente mi controlador en especial `return response()->json($contacto);`

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {

   $rules = array(
       'nombre' => 'required|max:200',
       'email'=> 'required|max:200',
       'mensaje'=> 'required|max:1000',
       'celular'=> 'max:12',
   );
   $validator = Validator::make ( input::all(),$rules);
   if($validator->fails())

   return response::json(array('errors'=>$validator->getMessageBag()->toarray()));

   else{
     $contacto = new Contactos;
     $contacto->nombres=$request->get('nombre');
     $contacto->correo=$request->get('email');
     $contacto->pregunta=$request->get('mensaje');
     $contacto->celular=$request->get('celular');
     $contacto->save();
     return response()->json($contacto);
   }
 }
```

el navegador se refleja esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero que pongo en remplas de `json($contacto);`  para que salga así el resultado?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no termina de quedar clara la pregunta

Comment: A) Por ahora mi controlador retorna un json (como se ve el resultado primera imagen.        B) En lugar de un json quiero que retorne una palabra (imagen 2 seria lo que quiero), quizás no tenga que usar un json.

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente haz un `return $palabra` o incluso puedes usar `echo $palabra`

Answer (score 2):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#view-responses

Creo que lo correcto seria que siguieras utilizando un response. Revisa el enlace anterior para mas info sobre las responses en laravel. En el caso que pones de respuesta de ejemplo, podrias hacer esto:

```
$texto = "MF000";

return response($texto, 200);
```

Response admite dos parametros, el primero es el elemento que quieres enviar (si es una cadena, devolvera esa cadena), el segundo es el codigo http de respuesta. Por ej, en tu caso seria viable utilizar un 200 como respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

```
return 'texto';
```

### versión larga

Cuando un cliente hace una petición HTTP (GET,POST,etc.), se establece un canal TCP con el servidor web, y, como es un protocolo petición/respuesta, el  servidor siempre contesta usando el formato que le indica el protocolo HTTP.

Una respuesta consta de una línea de estado, unas cabeceras opcionales, un par de retornos de carro y el resto del mensaje (ver [RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)), siendo la linea de estado tal que así:

```
Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
```

Si no necesitamos construir una respuesta estándar HTTP, entonces nos sirve con devolver una cadena de caracteres como si fuera la línea de estado y será nuestro cliente el que tenga que 'adivinar' que significa nuestro mensaje.

Por otro lado, si queremos construir un mensaje estándar que nuestro navegador (u otro cliente) sepa interpretar entonces hay que devolver una cadena que contenga todas características del protocolo. Para facilitar la construcción de este tipo de mensajes Laravel nos proporciona la clase [Response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses).

Answer (score 0):

Al principio es algo que parece complicado, pero se resuelve de una manera muy sencilla:

```
else{
     $contacto = new Contactos;
     $contacto->nombres=$request->get('nombre');
     $contacto->correo=$request->get('email');
     $contacto->pregunta=$request->get('mensaje');
     $contacto->celular=$request->get('celular');
     $contacto->save();
     $msj = "MF000";
     return $msj;
   }
```

No obstante, a verdad a mi no termino de resultarme util.
La manera más sencilla que encontre de resolver esto, para seguir teniaendo acceso a la informacion de Json y al mensaje que quiero enviar fue crear un Arreglo de Arrays:

```
$array[0] = $contacto;
$array[1] = "MF000";
return response()->json($array);
```

De esta manera tienes acceso al mensaje y a la información, en caso de que requieras ambos.